# Why can't arrow function set an array in Node and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this object

```
const data = {
  users: require("../model/users.json"), // initial value
  setUsers: (newUsers) => {
    this.users = newUsers
 } 
}
```

The setUsers arrow function doesn't assign newUsers to this.users, like it doesn't have access to this.users. But if I change setUsers to a regular function it works.

```
setUsers: function (newUsers) {
    this.users = newUsers
 }
```

Now it assigns newUsers to this.users. Why it does that, I thought arrow functions and regular functions are the same?

Comment: Regarding "I thought arrow functions and regular functions are the same" ... see [5 Differences Between Arrow and Regular Functions](https://dmitripavlutin.com/differences-between-arrow-and-regular-functions/).

Comment: They are not the same, thanks.